# sending an email with java not receving email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
 @Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = null;
    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    Users p = usb.getMemberInfo(user);
    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(true);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("passenger", p);

    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String username =     // to write sender email here 
String password =   // To Write Password here
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.username", username);
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

String to = (String)session1.getAttribute(p.getEmail());
try {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));

    InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);


    System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

    //for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    //}
    message.setSubject("Forgot password");
    message.setText(p.getPassword());
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, username, password);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");

}
```

}

method getMemberInfo:

```
@Override
public Users getMemberInfo(String username) {
   String query = "SELECT M from Users M where M.username=:username";
   Query q = em.createQuery(query);
   q.setParameter("username", username);
   List results = q.getResultList();

   for (Object o:results) {
       Users m = (Users) o;
       return m;
   }

   return null;
```

}

the problem is I am not receiving any email. I do not know what the problem is. the user need to write the username and then get the email from database and send the password to the user email that is acquired from database too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good answer for your problem about not receiving the mails. But your first problem seems to be that you don't know what exactly the problem is that prevents the mail from being sent...

You should add a TransportListener to your Transport instance, and see what happens:

```
transport.addTransportListener(new TransportListener {
    public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
      //Invoked when a Message is succesfully delivered. 
    }
    public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent e)  {
      //Invoked when a Message is not delivered. 
      System.out.println("Message not delivered: " + e.getMessage())
      //should be a proper log message anyway...
    } 
    public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent e)  {
      //Invoked when a Message is partially delivered. 
    }
}) ;
```

Recommended links:

- [Transport](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Transport.html)
- [TransportListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/event/TransportListener.html)
- [TransportEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/event/TransportEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

in fact the code is good the problem was that i have to write:

```
String to = p.getEmail();
```

instead of :

```
String to = (String)session1.getAttribute(p.getEmail());
```

thanks for you help anyways

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to configure addition properties

```
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Comment: These are mostly the defaults, and wouldn't explain the problem.